# Apropos always returns several duplicate matches from whatis

Tags: osx, man

When I run `apropos` or `man -k` in bash, it always returns the same item (at least one) twice:

[image: Bash screen-dump]

**Question**

Why is it doing this; and would it indicate that there's a possible configuration issue with my system?

I'm using OSX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this link titled: [Subject: Re: omitting duplicates in apropos and
apropos-list - msg#00017](http://osdir.com/ml/lisp.gcl.devel/2003-02/msg00017.html), I found the information below.

> "Because a symbol might be available by way of more than one
>   inheritance path,  apropos might print information about the same
>   symbol more than once, or  apropos-list might return a list containing
>   duplicate symbols."

I also found from this link titled: [duplicate entires for apropos after 5.0.7 MP5 (Linux & Unix Question)](http://linux-unix.questionfor.info/wap_q_linux-unix_264259), which contained the below piece of information.

> I straightened out this problem by running `makewhatis`

Comment: This is the only resource i've been able to find too prior to submitting this question (thought my google-foo was failing me). I've tried re-running `makewhatis` but the issue seems to be persisting. Any other ideas?

Comment: Ugly but… `function() apropos { command apropos "$@" | uniq }`